# Allowing quotes in search term solrnet

Tags: solrnet

I've come across a problem when users are trying to search for terms with multiple works wrapped in quotes. I'm using SolrNet to query Solr.

For example, if the user searches for "fertilizer", I get back the correct results. However searching for "fertilizer report" brings back no results.

The only code that I can see that actually queries solr is shown below, where `term` is the search term, and `qo` are my query options that contain a start point and number of rows.

```
_solr.Query(string.IsNullOrEmpty(term) ? SolrQuery.All : new SolrQuery(term), qo);
```

I've had a look at article online, [see here](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md) that mention using `Quoted`, is this the correct way to go about doing this? Or is this something that should be configured in my schema/solr config files?

### UPDATE 1

Further to Mauricio's comment, I've added part of my solr config xml below that shows how I'm using dismax:

```
  <requestHandler name="select" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="defType">edismax</str>
  <int name="rows">10</int>
  <str name="df">title</str>
  <str name="qf">title^1000 text^1 item_type_search^0.1 category_search^0.1 topic_search^0.1</str>
  <str name="pf">title^1000 text^1 item_type_search^0.1 category_search^0.1 topic_search^0.1</str>
  <str name="facet">true</str>
  <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
  <str name="facet.field">category_id</str>
  <str name="facet.field">item_type</str>
  <str name="facet.field">topic_id</str>
  <str name="facet.date">sort_date</str>
  <str name="f.sort_date.facet.date.start">2000-01-01T00:00:00.00Z</str>
  <str name="f.sort_date.facet.date.end">2050-01-01T00:00:00.00Z</str>
  <str name="f.sort_date.facet.date.gap">+1YEAR</str>
</lst>
```

Looking at the [link here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) some of the parameters `qf`, `df` and `pf` I am using dismax.

Comment: What is the actual value of `term` and how is your query field configured? Are you using dismax?

Comment: By the value of `term` if you mean what the user is entering, it's shown in my example above _fertilizer report_. The searchable field contain (at index and query time) the `StandardTokenizerFactory` tokenizer and at index time has the `NGramFilterFactory` applied. I've updated my question above to include the contents of my request handler in the solr config. I had a look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser), and it looks like I am using dismax.

Comment: You don't need `Quoted=true` in that case. You should get the same results as when running `q=fertilizer+report` directly in a web browser against Solr.

Comment: In solr admin when I search for `fertilizer+report` or `"fertilizerreport"` I get no results. When I search for `fertilizer report` I then get results. I'm just not sure how I can allow for the quotes to be taken into account when end users use them as a means of performing a search.

Comment: The `+` I mentioned was meant to be an URL-encoded space. I recommend using the sample app for reference: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Sample-application.md